# Twitter post linked image size limits

Tags: image, twitter, photo

Does anyone know what the size limits are when you attach an image to a tweet?

The documentation speaks about display size but not large size limitations. When you click an image it goes to a large size from your browser.

I am trying to optimize upload size from mobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search for `twitter max image upload size` and clicking the first link reveals

> Max Size of  your photo can be 3MB.

http://www.technospot.net/blogs/twitter-galleries/

Comment: @Jacob Tomlinson it's not that quick of a google search :) even when i did find twitter's docs (which are lower than your SO answer on google), their own site is not very clear about the limits: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/media/uploading-media -- after scrolling down 75% of the page you see that media can be up to 15MB, but images can be up to 5MB, and images with tweets up to 3MB. that just isn't clear and wasn't easy to find... your answer is better. thanks.

Comment: @benny it was a quick search when I wrote this answer nearly four years ago. I'm glad you found it useful.